# Hot fixes for multiple branches in git

Tags: git

In Git I have two main branches: a stable branch, and a "beta" branch.

One group of people is using code compiled from the "beta" branch while most people are using code compiled from the stable branch. Every once in a while, the "beta" branch is merged with the stable branch, but not often. In between releases I sometimes make hotfixes to both the stable branch and the "beta" branch. I'm not sure what the best practice is in this situation, but I usually create a patch and apply it to both branches separately. I don't want to merge the "beta" branch onto the stable branch to distribute the hotfixes. I also don't want the stable branch users to wait a few months to merge in order to distribute a simple hotfix.

Is creating a patch the right thing to do in this situation? Or should I merge the stable onto the "beta" branch whenever I create a hotfix? It seems like a bad idea to me to merge stable back into "beta" when it usually goes the other way around (I could be wrong; I'm not a Git expert).

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [daggy fixes](http://wiki.monotone.ca/DaggyFixes/) wiki page for monotone.  It's one way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Why not [cherry-pick](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) your commit from one branch to another ? That way you'll carry across the commit information along with your committed change, and not have to merge complete branches.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but in case someone is wondering, I found this to be the best practice:

Patch and commit hotfixes on the stable branch
Continually merge stable branch into "beta" branch

I was a Git noob when I posted this question. I found this strategy to be much better than cherry picking (although that does work) because, when we finally decided the beta code was stable, we could more easily merge "beta" into stable. Hope that helps.